# Angular & RxJS5 - Retain values from inner Observable beyond a higher order Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am starting with an inner Observable from Angular's `route.params`.

I would like to be able to retain the values from the params 'beyond' the higher order observable `switchMap`, which in my cases performs an http call.

For instance:

```
this.data$ = this.route.params
    .switchMap(params => this.http.get('/api', { param1: params.param1, param2: params.param2 }))
    .map(([params, data]) => {
        //possible to get params AND data here? This returns undefined.
        return something
    })
```

Is it possible to have access to the params after the switchMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use forkJoin:

```
this.data$ = this.route.params
    .switchMap(params =>  
         Observable.forkJoin([
             Observable.of(params),
             this.http.get('/api', { param1: params.param1, param2: params.param2 })
    ])
    .map(([params, data]) => {

         return something
    })
```

Comment: cannot find better approach so going with this, thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

use ResultSelector argument of switchMap

> A function to produce the value on the output Observable based on the values and the indices of the source (outer) emission and the inner Observable emission. The arguments passed to this function are

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap

```
this.data$ = this.route.params
  .switchMap(params => this.http.get('/api', { param1: params.param1, param2: params.param2 }), 
    (params, data) => {
       return [params, data];
     })
    .map(([params, data]) => {
      //possible to get params AND data here? This returns undefined.
       return something
     })
```

Comment: Using the `.switchMap()` result selector is much more readable and less messy than using `.forkJoin()`